# How to display the label for 0 length bars when using a log axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, bar-chart

I'm using Python 3.9.7

I have some data that I'd like to plot as bar charts (sample code and pic below).

I want to plot the bar charts using a **logarithmic** y scale.

However, some of the bar values might be zero, so they won't show as a bar on the log scale, but I would still like to show the ***label*** for each bar even if it is zero. If I plot the y-axis linearly, the 0 label shows up, but not with log-scaling.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm not wedded to matplotlib if there are other ways of plotting.

Thank you.

[image: and]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


month1 = [11, 1200, 0]
month2 = [55, 14, 37]
month3 = [111, 222, 300]

labels = ['a','b','c']
x_positions     = np.arange(len(labels)) 
bar_width = 0.15  

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x_positions - bar_width, month1, bar_width, label=labels[0])
rects2 = ax.bar(x_positions, month2, bar_width, label=labels[1])
rects3 = ax.bar(x_positions + bar_width, month3, bar_width, label=labels[2])

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Count')
ax.set_xticks(x_positions, labels)
ax.set_yscale('log') # the 0 label will appear if I omit this line.
ax.legend()

ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects3, padding=3)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: The easier option is to use `ax.set_yscale('symlog')` instead of `'log'`. Also add `ax.margins(y=0.1)` to increase the distance from the annotations to the top spine. Use `for c in ax.containers: ax.bar_label(c, label_type='edge', padding=3)` instead of 3 calls to `.bar_label`.

Comment: See easier [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bROQX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zero bar label is not shown, because on this log scale, 0 is infinitely far below the other bars' tops, so technically it can't be seen.

You can of course add a label manually:

```py
ax.text(x = x_positions[2] - bar_width, 
        y = ax.get_ylim()[0] + 1, 
        s = '0',
        horizontalalignment='center')
```

The `+1` is there to match the `padding=3` of the other labels. You may need to change this for other scales.

This approach could be automated by iterating over all the values, e.g. like this (setting two more y values to zero for testing):

```py
month1 = [11, 1200, 0]
month2 = [55, 0, 37]
month3 = [0, 222, 300]

labels = ['a', 'b', 'c']
x_positions = np.arange(len(labels)) 
bar_width = 0.15 
y_min = 10

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.tight_layout()
ax.set_yscale('log') 
ax.set_ylim(y_min, 2000)
    
rects1 = ax.bar(x_positions - bar_width, month1, bar_width, label=labels[0])
rects2 = ax.bar(x_positions, month2, bar_width, label=labels[1])
rects3 = ax.bar(x_positions + bar_width, month3, bar_width, label=labels[2])

ax.set_ylabel('Count')
ax.set_xticks(x_positions, labels)
ax.legend()
    
ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects3, padding=3)

for x, month in enumerate([month1, month2, month3]):
    for x_offset, y in zip([-1, 0, 1], month):
        if y < y_min:
            ax.text(x = x + x_offset * bar_width, 
                    y = y_min + 1, 
                    s = str(y),
                    horizontalalignment='center')
```

[image: Barplot with log axis and three zero labels]